# Como baixar o arquivo usando wget em um website autenticado?

Tags: linux, post, https, auth, wget

Estou tentando fazer download de um arquivo de backup que esta localizado em um site autenticado utilizando o wget. Eu rastreei o comportamento http quando eu faço login através do meu navegador e estes são os parâmetros:

```
https://quire.io/login
continue: 
s_password: fakepass
s_rememberMe: true
s_username: hotuser@nottrue.com

POST https://quire.io/login
Origin: https://quire.io
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: https://quire.io/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cookie: _gat=1; qrui=!; DARTSESSID=50e062c9xxxe886805xxx01c156fdb1e; _ga=GA1.2.90xxxx980.149xxxx972; _gid=GA1.2.260xxxxx3.1496xxxxx6
```

Tentei algumas soluções indicadas, mas nenhuma delas funcionou. Eu tentei:

```
wget --user=myusername --password=mypassword https://test.mydomain.com/files/myfile.zip
```

Tentei também:

```
   # Log in to the server.  This can be done only once.
   wget --save-cookies cookies.txt \
    --post-data 'user=foo&password=bar' \
    http://server.com/auth.php


   # Now grab the page or pages we care about.
   wget --load-cookies cookies.txt \
    -p http://server.com/interesting/article.php
```

Tentei de outras maneiras também, mas sem sucesso:

Minha *URL* de download é semelhante a essa:

```
https://quire.io/r/export/project/projectName/file.csv
```

Comment: Olá, poderia traduzir sua pergunta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 wget -c -r http://site/arquivos.zip --http-user=usuario --http-passwd=senha
```

`-r` para ser recursivo 
`-c` continuidade no download